# Nativescript/angular: Background check API, display notification if conditions met

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am developing a Nativescript/angular app, that lets users report some habit data every day.

I want to implement something so that every day at 20.00, I check (using http) if the user has reported data for the day. If they have not, I want to display a notification.

I have looked at background tasks for angular, web workers, delegatesm, http-background tasks, and it is pretty confusing, what is the right way to do it - and samples for specifically nativescript/angular are very limited. So I ask here...

What is the "right" way to poll an API in the background and display a notification if a criteria is met - in Nativescript/Angular?

Comment: On application instance start create an observable with a delay that you subscribe to. Within the subscription handler create a new call also with a delay. Should be simple enough. What have you tried so far, what is not working, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Background Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) in Android, [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-android-background-services) is an example implementation on Github. In this example they use a periodic service, that is triggered every 15 minutes. If you want your service to be triggered at specific time, then you will have to use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to trigger your service.

For iOS, I don't think it's possible at all to schedule a job at a specific time you want. The system will decide when to trigger based on available resources. You may use [nativescript-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/nativescript-background-fetch) for this purpose.